A question regarding tautologies and quantifiers
We know that $(P \implies Q) \vee (Q \implies P)$ is a tautology,
yet the statement
$$ \forall x \, \left( x \in A \implies x \in B \right) \vee \left( x \in B \implies x \in A \right), $$
which simply means $$ A \subseteq B \vee B \subseteq A, $$ isn't necessarily true.
On the other hand, taking the tautology $$(P \implies Q) \wedge (Q \implies R) \implies (P \implies R)$$ and setting $$ P = x \in A, \ Q = x \in B, \ R = x \in C $$ then quantifying it universally gives $$ A \subseteq B \wedge B \subseteq C \implies A \subseteq C,$$ which is indeed true.
Why does quantifying the first tautology yield a false statement even though quantifying the second tautology yields a true statement?

It does not "simply mean" $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$. The quantifier applies to the disjunction, but does not distribute over the disjunction.

I asked something similar some time ago

I see the difference, but how does one interpret ∀x(x∈A⟹x∈B)∨(x∈B⟹x∈A)?

Assuming an extra pair of parentheses (otherwise the second half of the formula is unquantified), we would read it as "for any $x$ it holds that either $x\in A$ implies $x\in B$ or $x\in B$ implies $x\in A$". This is weaker than saying $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$.

I see, thank you for helping me understand.

If you're wondering about a specific example, take $A = {a,b}$ and $B= {b,c}$. Then your formula is true and neither is a subset of the other.

This question is different, @AnotherUser.  In this one, the universal quantifier's scope (absent in the link you provide)  $\forall x ( x \in A \implies x \in B) \vee \left( x \in B \implies x \in A \right),$ applies  only to the first disjunct, not the second, making the second subset claim invalid.  Different question altogether.

@amWhy Based on your above comment, you do understand that the above duplicate target isn't at all a genuine duplicate; so, have you mistakenly just closed this Question?? $\quad$ On a separate note, I'm not following your exclamation below (and thus your accompanying downvotes on my 2 Answers (below, and in the duplicate target)).


$$ \forall x \, \left( x \in A \implies x \in B \right) \vee \left( x \in B \implies x \in A \right)$$

The above sentence isn't equivalent to the logical validity
$$ \forall x \, \Big(\left( x \in A \implies x \in B \right) \vee \left( x \in B \implies x \in A \right)\Big),\tag1$$ which is what you actually mean.
Anyhow, sentence $(1)$ doesn't imply (though is logically implied by)
$$ \forall x \left( x \in A \implies x \in B \right) \;\vee\; \forall x \left( x \in B \implies x \in A \right),\tag2$$ which, instead of sentence $(1),$ is the actual meaning of

$$ A \subseteq B \vee B \subseteq A.$$



On the other hand, taking the tautology $(P \implies Q) \wedge (Q \implies R) \implies (P \implies R)\tag*{}$ and setting $ P = x \in A, \ Q = x \in B, \ R = x \in C \tag*{}$ then quantifying it universally gives $ A \subseteq B \wedge B \subseteq C \implies A \subseteq C,\tag*{}$ which is indeed true.

Same mistake, but this time, fortuitously, we have that these two sentences are logically equivalent to each other, since in fact both sentences are logical validities: $  ∀x\Big(((Px→Qx)∧(Qx→Rx))→(Px→Rx)\Big)\tag3$
$∀x(Px→Qx)∧∀x(Qx→Rx)→∀x(Px→Rx). \tag4$

Well explained!

The statement given by the OP isn't quantified universally!
